# Installing Windows 7 on a new partition

Tags: windows, formatting, partitioning

My laptop is two years old and it came with an original Windows 7 Home Premium pre-installed. Unfortunately, it had one partition and I didn't change this at the beginning. Now, I want to format the drive. When I tried to add a new partition, Windows itself just suggests to me a 4325 MB space out of 465 GB (120 GB free space). How can I create a partition big enough to install Windows 7? And where should I get the copy of Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

- Hold the Windows key and R
- type in `diskmgmt.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- right-click an unallocated (free area) then click `New Simple Volume`
- click `next` at the welcome page window that pops up
- Specify the size you want the partition to be
- assign the partition a drive letter
- format the partition to `NTFS file system`
- click finish and you're done

Comment: at mr roboto, there is no need for a recovery disc.

Comment: First, he should shrink the system partition. To do that he would have to defragment it. And this does not ensure that he will be able to shrink it to the size he wants to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GParted to make new partition and then resize it to your needs. GParted will move the data from the place where will be the new partition, so you can avoid loosing it. But this is a gentle process, think twice before each step. First, I would back up data on external HDD for that operation.

Answer (score -1):

@user1727426:  You didn't mention which brand of laptop you have, however most major brands permit you to make a set of **recovery discs**, which will revert the laptop back to factory settings (brand new.)  You should (if you can) create these immediately, regardless of what you decide.

Unfortunately, **using** these recovery discs generally wipes the PC hard drive, including any valuable data.  Recovery on **some brands** preserves your existing data prior to the actual deed, but not **all brands**.  It's a good idea to save your valuable documents and such before doing anything potentially destructive.

If you're able to create recovery discs, then you have a source for Windows 7, otherwise you'll have to contact the original source of the laptop, or purchase something.  Good luck....